# Solving partial recurrence equation with several recurrence indices

Tags: recursion, difference-equations

I'm trying to solve a recurrence relation for a function of three variables. It works with 2 variables but not with 3.
A simple example is:

```
RSolve[a[i + 1, j + 1, l + 1] == a[i, j, l] + 3, a[i, j, l], {i, j, l}]
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Edit:
The actual recurrence relation i want to solve is the following:

$$
C\left(h_1+1,h_2,h_3\right)=\frac{\left(h_1+h_2-h_3\right) C\left(h_1,h_2,h_3\right)}{2 h_1+2
   \text{j}_1-k-2}\\
 C\left(h_1,h_2+1,h_3\right)=\frac{\left(h_1+h_2-h_3\right) C\left(h_1,h_2,h_3\right)}{2 h_2+2
   \text{j}_2-k-2} \\
 C\left(h_1,h_2,h_3-1\right)=\frac{\left(h_1+h_2-h_3\right) C\left(h_1,h_2,h_3\right)}{2 h_3-2 \text{j}_3-3 (k+2)}
$$
It can be brought into the form of my original question of course.
However I know the solution to the problem already, it is a combination of Gamma-functions. But I am interested on how to solve it with Mathematica so I can use it on more complicated relations that will appear in the future.

Comment: This example may be too simple.  Can you provide the actual recurrence relation that you are trying to solve?

Comment: I have provided the actual recurrence relation i want to solve in the original post. As I stated there, I know the solution to it already. But I'd like to know if it's possible to solve it in Mathematica, so I can solve other problems like it.

Comment: Please verify the third equation of your edit.  I would expect the left side to be `C[h1, h2, h3 + 1]` rather than `C[h1, h2, h3 - 1]`.  I know how to answer your question but wish to be sure that the equations are correct before doing so.

Comment: The ```C[h1,h2,h3-1]``` is correct as it stands.

Comment: Is the recurrence equation do you wish to solve the composite of the three equations above, `C[h1 + 1, h2 +1, h3 + 1] == f[I, j, l] C[h1, h2, h3`.]  Or, do you wish to solve the set of  three equations explicitly?  The former can be solved without difficulty in terms of `Gamma` functions.  The latter is overdetermined, unless specific constraints are placed on the initial conditions.

Answer (score 2):

The question as first posted can be answered as follows.  First, consider the 2D case,

```
RSolve[a[i + 1, j + 1] == a[i, j] + 3, a, {i, j}] // Flatten
(* {a -> Function[{i, j}, 3 i + C[1][i - j]]} *)
```

By inspection, the 3D case must have as its answer,

```
{a -> Function[{i, j, l}, 3 i + C[1][j - i, l - i]]}
```

as can be verified by

```
Simplify[(a[i + 1, j + 1, l + 1] == a[i, j, l] + 3) /. %]
(* True *)
```

More generally, `a[i + 1, j + 1, l + 1] == a[i, j, l] + f[i, j], a, {i, j, l}` must have as its solution

```
{a -> Function[{i, j, l}, 
    Sum[f[m, j - i + m, l - i + m], {m, 0, i - 1}] + C[1][j - i, l - i]]}
```

which can be verified as above.  Likewise, `a[i + 1, j + 1, l + 1] == a[i, j, l]*f[i, j], a, {i, j, l}` must have as its solution

```
{a -> Function[{i, j, l}, 
    Product[f[m, j - i + m, l - i + m], {m, 1, i - 1}]*C[1][j - i, l - i]]}
```

Presumably, these can be applied to the additional request edited into the question, once its meaning has been clarified.